# Dynamically populate specific generic properties of a mock object with a specific subclass of the same generic type with Moq

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, moq

I'm trying to create a generic class that can build a `Mock` of a generic interface to assist me with various unit testing functions.

I need the built mock object to have all its `DbSet<T>` properties populated with  `TestDbSet<T>` instances (`TestDbSet<T>` inherits from `DbSet<T>`).

For a specific example, given the interface:

```
public interface IAppointmentSchedulerContext
{
    DbSet<ServiceCenter> ServiceCenters { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to have my `TestDbContextBuilder` class construct a mock instance where the `ServiceCenters` property is populated with an instance of a `ServiceCenter<T>`.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class TestDbContextBuilder<TDbContextInterface> where TDbContextInterface : class
{
    public TDbContextInterface Build()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<TDbContextInterface>();
        var dbSetProps = typeof(TDbContextInterface).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                                                                 pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
                                                                 typeof(DbSet<>));

        //populate all the DbSet<TEntity> properties (in dbSetProps) on the mock with TestDbSet<TEntity> instances

        return mock.Object;
    }
}
```

If I were doing this statically, outside of the generic builder, I would just do this:

```
mock.SetupProperty(m=>m.ServiceCenters).Returns(new TestDbSet<ServiceCenter>());
```

But how do this dynamically, for all the `DbSet<>` properties on the generic `TDbContextInterface` interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to  get this working.  The final code is:

```
public class TestDbContextBuilder<TDbContextInterface> where TDbContextInterface : class
{
    public TDbContextInterface Build()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<TDbContextInterface>();
        mock.SetupAllProperties();

        var dbSetProps = typeof(TDbContextInterface).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                                                                 pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==
                                                                 typeof(DbSet<>));
        foreach (var prop in dbSetProps)
        {
            var dbSetType = prop.PropertyType;
            var dbSetGenericType = dbSetType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var testDbSetType = typeof(TestDbSet<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(dbSetGenericType);
            var testDbSetInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(testDbSetType);

            prop.SetValue(mock.Object, testDbSetInstance);
            }

        return mock.Object;
    }
}
```

I was stuck for the longest time on why `prop.SetValue(mock.Object, testDbSetInstance);` was leaving the property `null`.  The key was to add a call to `mock.SetupAllProperties()` before trying to set a value.

---

I'm not *super* happy with this code just yet, because calling `Mock.Object` "locks down" the mock so that no more changes can be made to it.  I have so ideas for fixing it, but it will involve digging more deeply in expression trees.